# Create PartitionKey from a Document and a PartitionKeyDefinition

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Given a generic object of type `T : Document`, and a `PartitionKeyDefinition`, how do you get the `PartitionKey` corresponding to that resource?  I used reflection to handle some simple cases, but I have to imagine there's some built-in function to do this for all cases.  I'm not finding it though.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I created a document with the structure as follows:

```html
{
  "id": "73e799df-b7a5-7470-4f25-ee6c1811a5b4",
  "tblType": "search",
  "user": {
    "memberId": 2
  }
}
```

**Note:** The Partition Key is `/user/memberId`.

> Given a generic object of type T : Document, and a PartitionKeyDefinition, how do you get the PartitionKey corresponding to that resource?

I supposed that you want to retrieve the partition key from the document instance based on the `PartitionKeyDefinition`. I created the document model and retrieve the document as follows:

```
var results=client.CreateDocumentQuery<MyDocument>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId,
                DocumentCollectionId), "select * from c where c.user.memberId=2").ToList();
```

In order to retrieve the partition key from the given document object, you could refer to the follows code snippet:

```
var obj = JObject.FromObject(results[0]);
var result=obj.SelectToken("user.memberId"); //2
```

[image]